# Wrong conversion of datetime timezone aware object in template Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have 2 datetime object with timezone `Europe/Berlin` and `US/Eastern` that I initially set with `pytz`.

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 11, 10, 20, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 11, 12, 16, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

These times should be displayed as 10:20AM and 12:16PM respectively.

However, in my django template they are different, for example:

```
{{ value.departure_time.date_time|time:'f A'}} # >> 8:20 AM instead of 10:20AM
```

I must be doing something wrong obviously, any thoughts?

Comment: If you print the values in python (before passing them to the template), what values do you get?

Comment: If I print the datetime object before passing it into the template it return `2019-06-11 10:20:00+02:00` 'Europe/Berlin' datetime object

Comment: So you want to display these on time `UTC+1` if I understood it correctly?

Comment: I want to display them with the correct time reflected in the datetime object. Look at my first object `datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 11, 10, 20 ...` should display 10:20 AM but it's not

Comment: @Cyzanfar: did you set the `USE_TZ` setting to `True` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: yup I did. `USE_TZ = True`

Comment: @Cyzanfar Django converts the time to the timezone specified in your `TIME_ZONE` settings. I'm guessing it is `UTC`, if you haven't changed the defaults, in which case the output is not wrong.

Comment: But what if I want to display different times in terms of their local timezone? If I set the TIME_ZONE to for example 'US/Eastern' then the time won't be in the correct time displayed. For example when you search for flights, the departing time and arrival time are always in terms of the origin and destination city local time.

Comment: See this page in the official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone

Comment: thanks for that. Yeah I looked over that doc. but isn't it redundant to have to do {% {% timezone "Europe/Berlin" %} in your template when the datetime object already has the correct datetime you want to display?

Comment: @Cyzanfar I've added an answer. The solution is much simpler. You just need to call `timezone.activate` method to active whatever timezone you want Django to user during rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something new for me as well, as I just found this out. Hence, I'm adding this as an answer.

From Django docs:

> When you enable time zone support, Django converts aware datetime objects to the **current time zone** when they’re rendered in templates.

---

#### What is current time zone?

Again, from docs:

> The **default time zone** is the time zone defined by the `TIME_ZONE` setting.
>
> The **current time zone** is the time zone that's used for rendering.
>
> You should set the **current time zone** to the end user's actual time zone with `activate()`. Otherwise, the default time zone is used.

---

#### Solution:

Just call `timezone.activate` method in your view before rendering, and Django will render the time in whatever timezone you set.

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

def my_view(...):

    tzname = pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")
    timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))

    render(...)
```

#### To display multiple timezones in a single render:

You can use either the [`timezone` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-timezone) or the [`timezone` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone) to override timezone in a particular portion of a template:

```
{% load tz %}

<!-- Using the filter -->
{{ value|timezone:"Europe/Paris" }}

<!-- Using the tag -->
{% timezone "Europe/Berlin" %}
    Berlin time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

Comment: what if I want to display 2 different timezone in one template? again kind of referring back to the flight search example

Comment: ok cool. I'm intrigued by why they design it this way. There should be a legitimate reason but I don't see it right now.

Comment: @Cyzanfar There's a `timezone` [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-timezone) and [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone), which you can use to override timezone in a specific portion of the template.

Comment: yup saw that. I was trying to avoid doing that but I guess that's my only option right now. Thanks for the answer :)